# How to avoid automatic entity update on Hibernate ValidationException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation, orm

I having a `spring` method: where I am validating the entity after constructing of object, which was previously fetched from DB.

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor={ValidationException.class})
    public Object approve(Command command) throws ValidationException {
        Object obj = merger.mergeWithExistingobject(command); // where I am fetching object from DB with old values and construct the new object

        validatorService.validate( obj ); // which throws ValidationException

        return saveObject(obj);
    }
```

But unfortunately even after the `ValidationException` was thrown. The values still get persisted in DB. How can I avoid this situtation.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't commiting changes in `mergeWithExistingobject`?

Comment: Is `validatorService` under spring control ? Post `ValidatorService` code please.

Comment: @Suganthan can you provide the exception log ?

Comment: @DraganBozanovic, yes I am sure.I am getting an object from DB and updating new changes that it.

Comment: @PawełGłowacz yes it is spring managed bean

Comment: @Sunil I didn't understand your question. Which log?

Comment: maybe your merger starts it's own transaction? Did you checked the transaction propagation settings?

Comment: @Nadir, it is in different host. I too thinking same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can evict the entity on `ValidationException`:

```
try {
    validatorService.validate( obj );
} catch (ValidationException e) {
    entityManager.detach(obj);
    //Or with Hibernate API
    //session.evict(obj); 
    throw e;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've never used spring but if this is the same as EJB then transactions are only rolled back when unchecked exceptions are thrown.

> When a java.lang.Exception is thrown from the EJB method, you obviously have to declare it in the method's signature with thethrows keyword. What happenes in this case as follows 1) the transaction gets commited 2) the exception is rethrown to the client

Taken from [this link](http://palkonyves.blogspot.be/2013/04/exceptions-and-transactions-in-ejb.html?m=1)

Comment: Yes you are right. But In my case even if `exception` thrown. transaction will get commited because if `isDirty` check